# shutil.rmtree does not remove directory

Tags: python-3.x

I'm struggling with one error for few hours now. I'm making a setup.exe for my program. Each time I install it I want old dirs and files to be removed and created again. The code I use for that is:

```
import os
import shutil

data_path = os.path.join(os.environ['HOMEDRIVE'], '\ProgramData', 'MyDir')

shutil.rmtree(data_path, ignore_errors=True)

os.makedirs(data_path)
```

When I run this I see an error `<FileExists> You can not create file that already exists: 'C:\\ProgramData\\MyDir'`

Comment: Try to remove the `ignore_errors=True` to see if you are getting any errors during the `sutil.rmtree(` run for more information.

Comment: Now it says `PermissionError: [WinError5] Permission denied: 'C:\\ProgramData\\MyDir' [1692] Failed to execute script`.  I've noticed that on some computers it works wiouth issues and on some it throws that error. I've tried on five and on two it doesn't work.

Comment: I've changed permission for my Setup.exe. I set it to run as administrator. Now it works everywhere even when I just copy this .exe.